# Mockito Spring Boot gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am unable to run a unit test for my spring boot application at the Service Layer as it gives me null pointer exception at line `List<Student> expectedList = studentService.findAl();`. But if I invoked the mock directly it works `List<Student> expectedList = studentRepository.findAll();`. The studentRepository is inject in the studentService. Can anyone illustrate what the problem is?
TestClass:

```
import com.demo.student.demo.entity.Student;
import com.demo.student.demo.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class StudentServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private StudentServiceImpl studentService;

    @Test
    public void findAll(){
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        studentList.add(new Student(1, "person1", "person1@mail.com"));
        studentList.add(new Student(2, "person2", "person2@mail.com"));

        when(studentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(studentList);

        List<Student> expectedList = studentService.findAl();

        assertEquals(0, expectedList.size());
    }


}
```

and the Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

the service interface:

```
public interface StudentService {

    public List<Student> findAl();
    public Student findById(long id);
    public Student saveOrUpdate(Student student);
    public void deleteById(long id);

}
```

and the service implementation:

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Student> findAl() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Student findById(long id) {
        Optional<Student> student = studentRepository.findById(id);
        boolean exist = student.isPresent();
        return exist? student.get() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Student saveOrUpdate(Student student) {
        studentRepository.save(student);
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(long id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some modifications to your code.
The change that I did was in the `StudentServiceImpl` class. I removed the `@Autowired` annotation and did constructor injection.

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

public StudentServiceImpl(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
    this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
}

//others are same
}
```

And in the test class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StudentServiceImplTest {

private StudentService studentService;
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

@Test
public void findAll(){
    studentRepository = mock(StudentRepository.class);
    studentService = new StudentServiceImpl(studentRepository);
    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentList.add(new Student(1, "person1", "person1@mail.com"));
    studentList.add(new Student(2, "person2", "person2@mail.com"));

    when(studentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(studentList);

    List<Student> expectedList = studentService.findAl();

    assertEquals(2, expectedList.size());
 }
}
```

Now I can see the test passing.

[image]

Also, read this [article](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) which says "Get rid of @InjectMocks".

I hope it helps you :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: It worked man!, I was also able to run it with autowire and mockbeans along with springbootest annotation. But one more question please: why didn't it work when I made the instantiation in @Before? shouldn't it be executed before each test?

Comment: When you use springboottest annotation, you are loading the whole ApplicationContext. So, this is a preferred way at least for now. 
Ok, let me check that as well.

Comment: @m.y.m Before is a JUnit 4 annotation. You're using JUnit 5, where the equivalent is Before each. The Before annotation is ignored by JUnit 5.

Answer (score 1):

The mock you are configuring here:

```
    StudentRepository studentRepository = mock(StudentRepository.class);
```

Is not injected into the service. Remove the initialisation of studentRepository inside your test and just use the one you have already annotated with @Mock.

Comment: it gives now null pointer exception at that line:
when(studentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(studentList);

Comment: Two things, move the initialisation of the StudentRepository mock to be above the initialisation of StudentService and also use StudentServiceImpl instead.

Comment: I moved the Mock to be above InjectMocks and used the class implementation StudentServiceImpl instead of the interface but nothing changed. Still NPE at line: when(studentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(studentList);

Comment: @m.y.m edit your question and add the code you're now using.

Comment: Also, post the **complete** code of the test class, starting at line 1. The imports matter.

Comment: Yes, if you have followed the steps suggested you will not get NPE.

Comment: Done. You can find the updated test class and the imports

Comment: You have no annotation, and no code in a Before each method, that would tell Mockito to handle the Mock and InjectMocks annotations. Read the doc to know how to do that.

Comment: A simpler, cleaner way would be to use constructor injection rather than field injection, to create the mock imperatively, and to call the service constructor yourself. No need for annotations then.

Comment: I managed to figure it out by using the annotation "SpringBootTest" before the test class, and have the repository as MockBean and Autowiring the service so the context will be running and the autowiring between the service and repo will take place.

Comment: You turned a unit test into an integration test loading the whole spring context. Bad idea.